# Math done in a 10x10 two dimensional array does not compute correctly

Tags: java, arrays

I set up a two dimensional array, 10 by 10, and each slot is (x*y) for its respective position. I'm trying to add up all numbers in columns 3, 5, and 7 into cTotal and add up all numbers in rows 2, 4, and 6 into rTotal. My coding seems sound but I just can't seem to make it work. Any ideas?

```
public static void arrayMath()
{
    int cTotal = 0;
    int rTotal = 0;
    //int tDiffValue = (rTotal - cTotal);

    int twodimarr[][] = new int[10][10];

    int row = 10; 
    int col = 10;
    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;

    for(x = 0; x < row; x++)
    {
        for(y = 0; y < col; y++)
        {
            twodimarr[x][y] = x*y;
        }
    }

    for(x = 0; x < row; x++)
        {
        for(y = 0; y < col; y++)
            {
            if( (x+y) < col )
            {
        //System.out.print( " " );
        }
    //System.out.print(" " + (twodimarr[x][y]));
    }
    //System.out.println();
    }

    for(x = 0; x < twodimarr.length; x++)     //Problems start down here.
      {
        for( y= 0; y<twodimarr.length; y++)
        {
            if(y == 2 || y == 4 || y == 6)
            {
            rTotal = ((rTotal + twodimarr[x][y]));
            }
        }
      }
      System.out.println("rTotal is " + rTotal + ".");

      for(x = 0; x < twodimarr.length; x++)
      {
          for(y = 0; y < twodimarr.length; y++)
          { 
             if(x == 3 || x == 5 || x == 7)
             {
             cTotal = ((cTotal + twodimarr[x][y]));
             }
          }
      }
      System.out.print("cTotal is " + cTotal + "."); 

}
```

Comment: What problem you having?

Comment: The addition isn't work. cTotal should be 540 and rTotal should be 405. I'm getting 675 for cTotal and 540 for rTotal.

Comment: And what you getting?

Comment: Achintya, edited my first response.

Answer (score 1):

x==3 isn't the third column, it's the 4th(0,1,2,3).  That meaning it's the column of 3*0, 3*1, etc. and the 675/540 numbers are correct in that case.

Comment: Wow, thank you, Thomas. What a simple oversight. I was losing sleep over this. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Array indexes start at 0. To get the rows/columns you want you need to subtract 1 from the numbers you are checking. For rows 2, 4, 6 check if y == 1, 3, 5. For columns 3, 5, 7 check if x == 2, 4, 6.